# Build enumerator (printer) for { 0 ^ (3 ^ n) | n >=0} with at most 10 states including print and halt, limited alphabet?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computation-theory, turing-machines

I have a task to build an enumerator (a turing machine which also prints to the output tape and outputs it by going to the `print` state) for the language `{0 ^ (3 ^ n) | n >= 0}` where:

1) The number of states must be at most 10 (**including** `print` and `halt` states, they are part of the 10 states)

2) `Gamma`, the printer alphabet is `{0, x, space}` and **nothing more**.

3) The output tape alphabet is `{0}`.

I've tried numerous times to build it with at most 10 states but managed to use 11 and not 10. My idea was to erase each `0` with a space, then iterate past a certain delimiter say `X`, and write 3 `0s` for each deleted `0` before the delimiter.  For example `space|x|space,space,space|x|000000000|x|`. `"|"` is just to emphasize the delimiter for this question,   the spaces are the previous `0's` overwritten - after overwriting each `0` with `space` i iterate past the `X` and append 3 `0s` at the end.

Each time i failed miserably lacking one more state. I've run out of ideas...help ?

Thanks

Comment: What you describe here does not seem to be a standard turing machine. Can you add some description of the machine you are using?

Comment: Add your 11 state solution to your question. So we can get a better idea what you are looking for.

Comment: Could this be better suited for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of machines that can do this. Here's an example of one. It happens to have a smaller number of states than required.

The basic idea is this:

1. start off by printing `0^(3^0) = 0^1 = 0` to the tape.
2. immediately after doing so, enter `print` since `0` is a string we need to enumerate.
3. after printing, convert all `0` on the tape to spaces, reading left to right
4. after converting all `0` to spaces, convert the rightmost space to a `0`, then add two `0` to the end of the tape
5. continue step 4 until all spaces are erased
6. the tape contents are a new string to enumerate, since we took a previous string of the form `0^(3^n)` and tripled every occurrence of `0`, giving the string `0^(3^(n+1))`.

The states look something like this:

```
 Q     T    Q'    T'    Mv
--    --    --    --    --
q0     x    pr     0    same
print  0    q1    sp    same
q1     0    q1    sp    right
q1     x    q2     x    left
q2     x    pr     x    right
q2    sp    q3     0    right
q2     0    q2     0    left
q2     x    pr     x    right
q3     0    q3     0    right
q3     x    q4     0    right
q4     x    q2     0    left
```

And here's what it looks like up through printing `0^(3^2) = 0^9`:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ q0
x0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ pr
x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ q1
x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q1
x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ q2
x0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q3
x00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q4
x000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q2
x000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q2
x000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ q2
x000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
^ q2
x000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ pr
x 00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q1
x  0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q1
x   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ^ q1
x   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q2
x  0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ^ q3
x  00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     ^ q4
x  000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ^ q2
x  000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q2
x  000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q2
x 0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ^ q3
x 0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ^ q3
x 0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     ^ q3
x 0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      ^ q3
x 00000xxxxxxxxxxxxx
       ^ q4
x 000000xxxxxxxxxxxx
      ^ q2
...
x 000000xxxxxxxxxxxx
 ^ q2
x0000000xxxxxxxxxxxx
  ^ q3
...
x0000000xxxxxxxxxxxx
        ^ q3
x00000000xxxxxxxxxxx
         ^ q4
x000000000xxxxxxxxxx
        ^ q2
...
x000000000xxxxxxxxxx
^
x000000000xxxxxxxxxx
 ^ pr
...
```